# mounting a docker volume to a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-container

**This Works**

To create the docker volume without specifying the disk size:

```
  docker volume create disk1
```

To  mount the volume(disk1) to a container

```
  docker run -itd -v disk1:/data ubuntu
```

**This is Not Working**

Now creating the docker volume by specifying a size of 100mb

```
  docker volume create --name disk2 --opt o=size=100m
```

To  mount the volume(disk2 which is of size 100 MB) to a container

```
  docker run -itd -v disk2:/data ubuntu
```

when I run these commands I was getting the following error

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/disk2/_data': missing device in volume options.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error occurs because set of driver options are missing

"--opt type=" and "--opt device=" is mandatory when you are providing  with size of the docker volume "--opt o=size="

So create volume with all the mandatory options and link with the container.

try

```
 docker volume create --name disk2 --opt type=tmpfs --opt device=tmpfs --opt o=size=100m
```

then

```
 docker run -itd -v disk2:/data ubuntu
```

It works.